# Report.txt file in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

what are the statistics contained by a report.txt file in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a Statspack (or its progenitor UTLBSTAT/UTLESTAT) report, look [here.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/statspac.htm#34837)  It's been removed from the 10g documentation in favor of Automatic Workload Repository, which Oracle then saw fit to charge extra for.